# How to show image on the right hand side of the notification in android

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I am working on android application . I need to create a notification for the app.
I am able to create it successfully using :

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_notifications.htm

I know NotificationCompat.Builder setNumber(int Number) . It sets the number on the notification on the right hand side . But instead of the number i want to show a small icon.
Do i need to use a custom layout , Because i am not able to find any API for this .
How do i do it .

Comment: Try with Custom Notifications refer http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-custom-notification-tutorial/

Comment: @SathishKumarJ In method CustomNotification(), when we are using builder.setContent(remoteViews); , then why do we need to use builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logosmall) . Becuase As i understand setContent is for customview setting and setSmallIcon is for standard view setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show an image at the bottom right end of the notification, we have to use the following APIs

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(baseContext).setLargeIcon(large_icon)
                .setSmallIcon(small_icon);
```

For devices running up to android Kitkat the `setLargeIcon` sets the image at the left end, while the `setSmallIcon` sets the image at the bottom right end of the notification.

For devices running on higher than Kitkat 
the `setLargeIcon` sets the image at the Left end, while the `setSmallIcon` sets the image at the bottom right end of the Large Image.